# EditField in Black Berry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-editfield

I want to create the `EditField` which allow ***Numeric Values***, ***Comma*** and other values are ignore in **Blackberry**.

So How I can achieve this by programming code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be achieved by using the EditField class with the Four arguments according to your need.

```
        EditField ef = new EditField(0, "0", 3, EditField.FILTER_NUMERIC)
```

Add this field to a screen or a manager

The above code would make the field accept only the integer values. And if it is a Virtual keypad, it would not even show other characters/aplhabets on the keypad

Hope this solves your problem.
Keep Coding
Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

use filter for this.....

```
_numberEditField = new EditField(_name, "");
_numberEditField.setFilter(TextFilter.get(TextFilter.NUMERIC));
add(_numberEditField);
```